# When a figure is on the page, a new one is moved to the next one?

Tags: floats, positioning

Here is an example of a TeX code I use:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{a}
    \caption{some caption}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{b}
    \caption{some caption}
  \end{minipage}
%\vspace{}
\centering
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{c}
    \caption{some caption}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{d}
    \caption{some caption}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{e}
\caption{some caption}
\end{figure}
```

The last figure is always moved to a new page, why is that the case and how do I make it stay on the same page as the above?

Comment: Likely because there's no room. Try moving `\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{e}
\caption{some caption}` into the first `figure` environment.

Comment: Not a space issue for sure

Comment: Well, I couldn't really know the height of your images ...

Comment: There are limits on how many floats are allowed on the bottom of the page and how large they are.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat?s=1|1.9353  Some document classes do not allow ANY floats on the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Put everything in the same `figure` environment, that will ensure that they end up on the same page, as `figure`s cannot be broken across pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{some caption}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{some caption}
  \end{minipage}

\medskip

  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3cm]{example-image-c}
    \caption{some caption}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3cm]{example-image}
    \caption{some caption}
  \end{minipage}

\medskip

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3cm]{example-image-16x10}
\caption{some caption}
\end{figure}
\kant
\end{document}
```